# How to set a xaml resource value to a constant in code behind

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to override the width of the vertical scrollbar for a WPF application. Adding the following code to a resource dictionary referenced by the App.xaml works a treat:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">50</sys:Double>
```

However, I need to access the value from code-behind elsewhere in the application, so I would like to set this to a code-behind constant.

```
public static class MyConstants
{
    public static double ScrollBarWidth = 50;
```

But how do I set this value to the double in xaml?
I've tried all of these without success:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:MyProject">

    <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}" Binding="{x:Static constants:MyConstants.ScrollBarWidth}" />
    <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}" Source="{x:Static constants:MyConstants.ScrollBarWidth}" />
    <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}" Value="{x:Static constants:MyConstants.ScrollBarWidth}" />
```

Comment: Bindings can only be done on properties. `ScrollBarWidth {get; set;} = 50;` But I am not sure with static values. perhaps you should try

Comment: @NawedNabiZada I actually can't set the binding to the Resource fullstop: `The property 'Binding' was not found in type 'Double'`. Maybe I just need to find the magic keyword to assign it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the entry to your resources and get it back from there in code.

```
        var key = SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey;
        Application.Current.Resources[key] = 42d;
        Double vsbWidth = (Double)Application.Current.Resources[key];
        Console.WriteLine(vsbWidth.ToString());
```

If you wanted to override the value at (say) window scope you could do this.Resources rather than application.

Comment: Great! In my app.xaml.cs I just put this in and I'm done `Current.Resources[SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey] = MyConstants.ScrollBarWidth;`

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me

```
<x:Static x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}" Member="local:Constants.scrollBarWidth" MemberType="{x:Type sys:Double}"></x:Static>
```

[x:Static Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-static-markup-extension)

Comment: This looks promising but I get an error `'System.Double.constants:MyConstants.ScrollBarWidth' StaticExtension value cannot be resolved to an enumeration, static field, or static property` How did you declare your constant property?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `x:Static` markup extension without `MemberType` works for me:

```
<x:Static x:Key="myKey" Member="local:MyConstants.ScrollBarWidth"></x:Static>
```